# Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to call a function from another controller.

```
$this->load->library('../controllers/Sondage');
$data11 = $this->Sondage->resultats($evaluation_id,1);
```

This results in the following error:

`Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php`

How can I call this function from another controller?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is pretty unclear and it's unlikely that will get a proper answer. Take a minute to read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and edit your post.
In particular read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to create a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example".

Comment: You can't load controllers with in controllers in normal codeigniter you should use the third party extension HMVC

Answer (score 0):

Are the controllers on the same directory? If it on the same directory, you could try :

```
require_once('sondage.php');
$sondage = new sondage();
$data11 = $sondage->resultats($evaluation_id,1);
```

Comment: thanks for your answear, i already tried  that, but still have the problem